# rake-pipeline performance

Tags: rake, rake-pipeline

We're using `Rake::Pipeline::Middleware` to serve a rake-pipeline project with Rack. It seems incredibly slow, like it's rebuilding *everything* whenever a file has changed.

Are we doing something wrong? Is there something we can do to speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compressing the files you should put a conditional in your `Assetfile` to not compress in development. The `concat` filters are not that slow. The `uglify` and `yui_css` filters are and you don't need the compression for dev.

Comment: Thanks! We're not uglifying in development actually. Plenty of Sass and CoffeeScript though.

Comment: ah, yeah that will be slow as well. I assume you're using Guard? Your Guardfile might be too aggressive in how it rebuilds (everything?)

Comment: There's a Guardfile, but when you run `rackup` with the `Rake::Pipeline::Middleware`, guard shouldn't be used at all, should it? There's no reference to any guarding in `config.ru` or `Assetfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `therubyracer` gem has helped as well, cutting total compile time by factor 3. We are compiling a lot of CoffeeScript, and having `therubyracer` available avoids shelling out to Node.

Comment: Great tips! Did you do anything in addition to requiring the gem on top of the Assetfile?

Comment: I think it will actually require it [automatically](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/blob/1e87b3735176c6e656e4b5ba18ed10214b321ba5/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb#L98), so all you have to do is add therubyracer to your Gemfile.